# localStorage parameter undefined when back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 3 pages.

1. Category page - shows a list of movie categories e.g. Horror, Romance, Thriller.
2. Movie List - retrieves a list of movies based on category selected
3. Movie Details - retrieves movie details when a movie is selected from movie list

From "Category page" to "Movie List", i listen to the click event and store the category id into localStorage before changing page to "Movie List".

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event, ui) {
  var data_id = $(this).attr('id');
  // store some data
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    localStorage.category = data_id;
  }
  // Change page
  $.mobile.changePage("#movelist");
});
```

From "Movie List" to "Movie Details", i add the movie ID into localStorage and change page to "Move details".

```js
$(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    localStorage.movie_id= $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(localStorage.category);
  }
  $.mobile.changePage("#movie-details");
});
```

The problem i am facing is that when the back button is pressed from the "Movie Details" page, the "Movie List" page is empty because the category ID in the localStorage becomes "undefined".

```js
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#movielist', function() {
  //empty list to prevent duplicates
  $('#movie-list').empty();
  //get attractions JSON and populate list based on category
  $.getJSON("./json/movielist.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      if (val.category == localStorage.category) {
        $('#movie-list').append("<li id='" + val.id + "' class='ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child'><a class='ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r'><img src='" + val.image +
                                "' class='thumbnail'/><h2>" +
                                val.name + "</h2></a></li>");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Question 1: localStorage data will be cleared when back button is pressed? Why?

Question 2: How do i make sure that the category is retained so that my movielist will still load?

Appreciate all help given. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event, ui) {
    var data_id = $(this).attr('id');
    // store some data
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem('category', data_id);
    }
    // Change page
    $.mobile.changePage("#movelist");
});
$(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem('movie_id', $(this).attr("id"));
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('category'));
    }
    $.mobile.changePage("#movie-details");
});
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#movielist', function() {
    //empty list to prevent duplicates
    $('#movie-list').empty();
    //get attractions JSON and populate list based on category
    $.getJSON("./json/movielist.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if (val.category == localStorage.getItem('category')) {
                $('#movie-list').append("<li id='" + val.id + "' class='ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child'><a class='ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r'><img src='" + val.image +
                        "' class='thumbnail'/><h2>" +
                        val.name + "</h2></a></li>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Um what is different? `localStorage.category` and `localStorage.getItem('category')` is the same thing, same with setting the item.

Comment: yea thats what i thought